# Get count from Array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of arrays below. With ES6, how can I get a count of each value `Good`, `Excellent` & `Wow` into a new array e.g `[{name: Good, count: 4} {name: Excellent, count: 5}, {name:Wow, count:2}]` in dynamic style. I am attempting to use `Object.assign` but I am failing to "unique" out the count of the key plus instead, I need to use an array as I am trying to render this out on the front end. Do I need to use `reduce`? how?

```js
let k = 0
const stats = {}
const remarks = [
  [{name: "Good"}],
  [{name: "Good"}, {name: "Excellent"}],
  [{name: "Good"}, {name: "Excellent"}, {name: "Wow"}],
  [{name: "Good"}, {name: "Excellent"}, {name: "Wow"}],
  [{name: "Excellent"}],
  [{name: "Excellent"}]
]

remarks.forEach((arr) => {
  arr.map((e) => {
    Object.assign(stats, { [e.name]: k = k + 1 })
  })
})

console.log(stats);
```

**Output:**

> `stats: {Good: 8, Excellent: 11, Wow: 9}`

Which is Incorrect plus I need to use an array.

**Expected output:**

> `[{name: Good, count: 4} {name: Excellent, count: 5}, {name:Wow, count:2}]`

Comment: why have you got type definitions? Are you sure you aren't using typescript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flatten the array of arrays and reduce it starting with an object like : `{ Good: 0, Excellent: 0, Wow: 0}`

then `.map` the `Object.entries` of the result to transform it to an array :

```js
const remarks = [
  [{ name: "Good" }],
  [{ name: "Good" }, { name: "Excellent" }],
  [{ name: "Good" }, { name: "Excellent" }, { name: "Wow" }],
  [{ name: "Good" }, { name: "Excellent" }, { name: "Wow" }],
  [{ name: "Excellent" }],
  [{ name: "Excellent" }]
];

const result = Object.entries(
  remarks.flat().reduce(
    (all, { name }) => {
      all[name] += 1;
      return all;
    },
    { Good: 0, Excellent: 0, Wow: 0 }
  )
).map(([name, count]) => ({ name, count }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I get a "Property 'flat' does not exist on type '{ name: string; }[][]'."  error on `flat`

Comment: @colin_dev256 what browser?

Comment: You're just missing a type def then

Answer (score 3):

You can try below logic:

```js
var data = [[{name: "Good"}],[{name: "Good"}, {name:"Excellent"}],[{name: "Good"}, {name:"Excellent"}, {name:"Wow"}],[{name: "Good"}, {name:"Excellent"}, {name:"Wow"}],[{name:"Excellent"}],[{name:"Excellent"}]]

var nData = [];

(data || []).forEach( e => {
  (e || []).forEach(ei => {
    var i = (index = nData.findIndex(d => d.name === ei.name)) >=0 ? index : nData.length;
    nData[i] = {
      name: ei.name,
      count : (nData[i] && nData[i].count ? nData[i].count : 0)+1
    }
  });
});

console.log(nData);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can use reduce, then convert the result into an array of objects:

```
const counts = remarks.reduce((result, list) => {
  list.forEach(remark => {
    result[remark.name] = (result[remark.name] || 0) + 1;
  });
}, {});
const finalResult = [];
for (let name in counts) {
  finalResult.push({name, count: counts[name]});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this pretty easily by:

1) Flattening the nested array into 1 single level array.

2) Iterating over the flat array and create a "count map" by using `Array.prototype.reduce`

For example:

```js
const remarks = [
  [{
    name: 'Good'
  }],
  [{
    name: 'Good'
  }, {
    name: 'Excellent'
  }],
  [{
    name: 'Good'
  }, {
    name: 'Excellent'
  }, {
    name: 'Wow'
  }],
  [{
    name: 'Good'
  }, {
    name: 'Excellent'
  }, {
    name: 'Wow'
  }],
  [{
    name: 'Excellent'
  }],
  [{
    name: 'Excellent'
  }]
]

const flatten = arr => arr.reduce((accum, el) => accum.concat(el), [])
const map = flatten(remarks).reduce((accum, el) => {
  if (accum[el.name]) {
    accum[el.name] += 1;
  } else {
    accum[el.name] = 1;
  }
  return accum;
}, {});

console.log(map)
```

Answer (score 1):

First find the counts using `reduce` than pass that to another function to get the desired view structure:

```js
const Good = 1,
      Excellent = 2,
      Wow = 3;

const remarks = [
  [{name: Good}],
  [{name: Good}, {name:Excellent}],
  [{name: Good}, {name:Excellent}, {name:Wow}],
  [{name: Good}, {name:Excellent}, {name:Wow}],
  [{name:Excellent}],
  [{name:Excellent}]
];

/*
[{name: Good, count: 4} {name: Excellent, count: 5}, {name:Wow, count:2}]
*/

function counts(remarks) {
  return remarks.flat().reduce((acc, v) => {
    const name = v.name;
    let count = acc[name] || 0;
    return {
    ...acc,
    [name]: count + 1
    }
  }, {});
}

function view(counts) {
   return Object.keys(counts).map(key => {
     let count = counts[key];
     return { name: key, count };
   })
}

console.log(view(counts(remarks)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Any time you are making a smaller set of data, or transforming data, in JavaScript reduce should be the first method you attempt to use. In this case, you may want to pair it with an indexer (hence preloading with an array of index and an array of result).

This works in one pass without needing to know the name values up front.

```js
const remarks = [
  [{name: "Good"}],
  [{name: "Good"}, {name: "Excellent"}],
  [{name: "Good"}, {name: "Excellent"}, {name: "Wow"}],
  [{name: "Good"}, {name: "Excellent"}, {name: "Wow"}],
  [{name: "Excellent"}],
  [{name: "Excellent"}]
];

const stats = remarks.reduce((p,c) => (
  c.forEach( ({name}) => {
    if(!p[0].hasOwnProperty(name)){
      p[1].push({name:name,count:0});
      p[0][name] = p[1].length - 1;
    }
    p[1][p[0][name]].count++;
  }),p),[{},[]])[1];
    
console.log(stats);
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more concise and definitely less readable approach (but it's worth to mention) could be:

```
const remarks = [
  [{ name: "Good" }],
  [{ name: "Good" }, { name: "Excellent" }],
  [{ name: "Good" }, { name: "Excellent" }, { name: "Wow" }],
  [{ name: "Good" }, { name: "Excellent" }, { name: "Wow" }],
  [{ name: "Excellent" }],
  [{ name: "Excellent" }]
];

const stats = Object.entries(
                remarks
                  .flat()
                  .reduce((acc, {name}) => (acc[name] = -~acc[name], acc), {})))
              ).map(([name, count]) => ({ name, count }));


console.log(stats);
```

It uses the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) in the reducer to returns the accumulator; and the [bitwise operator NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#(Bitwise_NOT)) to create a counter without the needs to initialize the object upfront with all the names.

Answer (score 0):

```
const flattenedRemarks = _.flatten(remarks);

const groupedRemarks = _.groupBy(flattenedRemarks, (remark) => remark.name);

const remarkCounts = _.mapValues(groupedRemarks, (group) => group.length);
```

Comment: Who said the OP is using Underscore?

Comment: @IceMetalPunk who said he couldn't?

Comment: The usual policy of StackOverflow answers is not to even change the style of the code unless necessary; requiring new libraries is a step beyond that. At least Robert should mention in the answer that Underscore is required to use his solution.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk eh, no, here's the usual policy: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335328/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question

Comment: The top answer to that question is "pretty much never". If "use jQuery" is "pretty much never" a good answer, why would "use Underscore" be better?

Comment: @IceMetalPunk the question was, "When is use jQuery *not* a valid answer."

Comment: You're right, I misread. On the other hand, the second topvoted answer: "

"When any of the following is true:

    It is the entire answer, with no explanation of exactly how jQuery helps
    When the problem can be solved simply without jQuery
    When the question specifically asks for no javascript frameworks
    When the question is tagged or mentions a competing framework
    When someone else already posted it"

I'd say this fits point #2 there.

Comment: The important key is, valid !== useful. you're free of course to express your opinion on that matter using the tools available.

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = {
    "mchale": {
        "classes":["ESJ030", "SCI339"], // get the length
        "faculty":["Hardy", "Vikrum"]   // get the length
     },
    "lawerence":{
        "classes":["ENG001"],  // get the length
        "faculty":["Speedman", "Lee", "Lazenhower"] // get the length
     }
};

const count = Object.keys(data).map(campusName => {
  const campus = data[campusName];
  return Object.keys(campus).map(key => campus[key].length).reduce((p, c) => p + c, 0);
}).reduce((p, c) => p + c, 0);
console.log(count);
```

Comment: would be nice if you leave some comment on your code, as it is not always self-explanatory why you addressed this solution